# Plutus transaction error PT5

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, cardano-cli, transaction, plutustx

I am building a transaction where I use the following function to make my datum and redeemer,

```
writeJSON :: PlutusTx.ToData a => FilePath -> a -> IO ()
writeJSON file = LBS.writeFile file . encode . scriptDataToJson ScriptDataJsonDetailedSchema . dataToScriptData . PlutusTx.toData
```

But when I build a transaction to consume an UTxO at the script address I get the following error,

```
Command failed: transaction build  Error: The following scripts have execution failures:
the script for transaction input 0 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The provided Plutus code called 'error'.
Script debugging logs: PT5
```

I am very certain that my redemeer and datum are correct. My onchain code is the following

```
data MyDatum = MyDatum
    { pubKey :: Integer
    } deriving (Show, Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON, ToSchema)

data MyRedeemer = MyRedeemer
    { privKey :: Integer
    } deriving (Show, Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON, ToSchema)

data Params = Params
    { params_p :: Integer
    , params_g :: Integer
    , params_bits :: Integer
    } deriving (Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON, ToSchema)

unsafeParams :: Params
unsafeParams = Params p g 64
        where
                p = safePrime64
                g = (safePrime64 - 1) `PlutusTx.Prelude.divide` 2

PlutusTx.makeIsDataIndexed ''MyDatum [('MyDatum, 0)]
PlutusTx.makeLift ''MyDatum
PlutusTx.makeIsDataIndexed ''MyRedeemer [('MyRedeemer, 0)]
PlutusTx.makeLift ''MyRedeemer
PlutusTx.makeLift ''Params

{-# INLINABLE mkValidator #-}
mkValidator :: Params -> MyDatum -> MyRedeemer -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkValidator (Params p g _) (MyDatum pub) (MyRedeemer priv) _ = pub == exponentiateMod g priv p
```

Where the the validator checks whether or not the redeemer is the exponent of the datum via modular exponentiation. Perhaps I incorrectly indexed my datum and redeemer with the `makeIsdataIndexed` function?

Comment: Your error means that the validator script returned an error. In the newer version of node, I think 1.33 or 1.34 you can see the exact error message which is thrown from the validator.

Comment: I am currently running 1.33, ill update to 1.34 and see what I get there. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

`PT5` alone means that the validator returned `False`. You can break down your script into multiple steps of computation and add some `traceIfFalse` calls along the way to see more context why it happend to be `False` overall.